# Embedded objects in fixtures raise "unable to find fixtures" errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data's fixtures adapter extensively to provide a lot of set-up data in my app. For one model ("Structure"), there is an array of embedded related objects ("Overlays"). When I load a Structure instance from the store, then query its `overlays` property, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find fixtures for model type App.Overlay
```

Both models are defined as follows (with a few other fields/relationships removed for clarity):

```
App.Structure = DS.Model.extend({
  // How this appears in lists
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  // Color to show this overlay with
  color: DS.attr('string'),
  // hash of overlay paths
  overlays: DS.hasMany('App.Overlay', { embedded: true })
});

App.Overlay = DS.Model.extend({
  view: DS.attr('string'),
  path: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I only need one fixture to demonstrate:

```
App.Structure.FIXTURES = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test Structure",
    "color": "#cc0033",
    "overlays": [{
        'view': 'Isometric',
        'path': "M17.5,19.508V8.626h-3.999v10.881c-1.404,0.727-2.375,2.178-2.375,3.869c0,2.416,1.959,4.375,4.375,4.375s4.375-1.959,4.375-4.375C19.876,21.686,18.905,20.234,17.5,19.508zM20.5,5.249c0-2.757-2.244-5-5.001-5s-4.998,2.244-4.998,5v12.726c-1.497,1.373-2.376,3.314-2.376,5.4c0,4.066,3.31,7.377,7.376,7.377s7.374-3.311,7.374-7.377c0-2.086-0.878-4.029-2.375-5.402V5.249zM20.875,23.377c0,2.963-2.41,5.373-5.375,5.373c-2.962,0-5.373-2.41-5.373-5.373c0-1.795,0.896-3.443,2.376-4.438V5.251c0-1.654,1.343-3,2.997-3s3,1.345,3,3v13.688C19.979,19.934,20.875,21.582,20.875,23.377zM22.084,8.626l4.5,2.598V6.029L22.084,8.626z"
    }]
}];
```

With those, I can load a Structure:

```
> var structure = App.fixtureStore.find(App.Structure, 0);
> structure.get('name');
"Test Structure"
```

But if I query its overlay, things go squirrely:

```
> structure.get('overlays');
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find fixtures for model type App.Overlay
```

What's up? Do I need to declare fixtures for this model, even if they're empty?

[Here is a jsfiddle showing the error](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/hA6VH/).

Comment: The docs are not very good. If anyone is interested, these are the issues I had to deal with to get Ember Data fixtures to work for me in general (with nested models): http://www.vinay.io/static/blog/2013/12_17.html

Comment: @Vinay: link is dead...

Comment: @JacobvanLingen sorry about that. :-\ I moved over to a new blog and the old posts are no longer served. Luckily, they were all barebones static HTML (for the most part), so here's a gist of the template for that post: https://gist.github.com/vhmth/da7c26263d3dc29b3276

Comment: Ah awesome, for uploading the gist. I did see that your blog was moved over, but I could not find the code. Btw, i fixed this problem by changing to the restadapter => If a key is missing, the rest adapter will do a call. After knowing the missing key I added that one to my fixtures + went back to the fixture-adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, [a little more tweaking to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/hA6VH/3/) shows that I do need to declare empty fixtures for the model:

```
App.Overlay.FIXTURES = [];
```

Comment: Hi @pjmorse, how would you do the same using ES6 modules? Eg where do you put the fixtures

Comment: I haven't worked with fixtures in ES6 modules yet, so I wouldn't be able to tell you.